# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "liegen" und "lügen"

Tags: meaning

My understanding is that they both mean `to lie`. But they seem to be used in different contexts. Could they refer to different kinds of `lying`?

Comment: This could easily be checked by looking the words up in a dictionary: [liegen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=liegen), [lügen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=lügen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Liegen` und `lügen` can be translated as `to lie` (resting horizontally) and `to lie` (not telling the truth) respectively.

---

> liegen (Resting horizontally or being located)

Examples for `liegen`:

> Ich liege im Bett (I'm lying in bed.)
>
> Berlin liegt im Osten von Deutschland. (Berlin is located in the eastern part of Germany.)

---

> lügen (not telling the truth)

Examples:

> Er lügt mich an. (He is lying to me.)
>
> Ich lüge jeden Tag. (I'm lying on a daily basis.)

Comment: Ok, reminds me of the joke about the woman diplomat who was sent abroad to lie (lügen) for her country (an American cliche). But she actually did her job by "lying" (liegen) for her country.

Comment: Note that you can easily do both kinds of lying in a bed. Even at the same time.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: And in either case, the purpose is is "verführen" (I believe that is the word).

Comment: They are Not the same English Verb, they are homonyms.

Comment: www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Lie&searchmode=none

Comment: @CarstenSchultz So? No one said that there is only one English verb `to lie`.

Comment: You did. "... the English verb"

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Added the "s", happy now?

Comment: I wished my happiness would depend only on that ;). But sorry, I hadn't noticed that this is an old question and hence not the best place for nitpicking.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Made it even clearer by reformulating the first paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

Liegen is to lie on a horizontal surface and lügen means to make up a story:

> Ich liege im Bett.

I am in bed

> Was ich sage, ist die Wahrheit und ich lüge nicht.

What I am saying is the truth and I don't lie.